# Enable Lead field history tracking via api

Tags: rest-api, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby gem `restforce` for `salesforce` api implementation.
I am not finding a way to enable the Lead history tracking using api.

Where as I can retreive the history if enabled from dashboard.

```
client.query "SELECT Id,OldValue,NewValue,Field,CreatedDate from LeadHistory"
```

Please help.

Comment: In order to use this you need to use metadata api which is SOAP based.

Comment: can it be achieved with 'soapforce' gem? https://github.com/TinderBox/soapforce

Comment: I don't think that gem would be useful. Since as per documentation it is for CRUD operations on records, here you want to touch metadata.